# MySQL Query sum

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I've got the following query

```
SELECT crm_presupuestos.fecha_alta, 
       crm_presupuestos.id_vendedor, 
Sum( 
`precio` * ( 100 - `crm_presupuestosdetalles`.`bonif` ) / 100 * `crm_presupuestosdetalles`.`cantidad`) AS LineaNeto
FROM   crm_presupuestos 
       RIGHT JOIN crm_presupuestosdetalles 
               ON crm_presupuestos.id_presupuesto = 
                  crm_presupuestosdetalles.id_presupuesto 
GROUP  BY crm_presupuestos.fecha_alta, 
          crm_presupuestos.id_vendedor 
HAVING (( Date(( crm_presupuestos.fecha_alta )) = Curdate() ));
```

This works okay, but I need it to sum all the `linea neto` of each `ID_Vendedor`. Also, I need a total at the end of this. Could somebody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(Fecha_Alta, 'Total') Fecha_Alta, ID_Vendedor, SUM(LineaNeto) LineaNeto 
FROM (SELECT cp.Fecha_Alta, cp.ID_Vendedor, SUM(Precio * (100-cpd.Bonif)/100*cpd.Cantidad) AS LineaNeto
      FROM CRM_PRESUPUESTOS cp
      RIGHT JOIN CRM_PresupuestosDetalles cpd ON cp.ID_Presupuesto = cpd.ID_Presupuesto
      GROUP BY cp.Fecha_Alta, cp.ID_Vendedor
      HAVING DATE(cp.Fecha_Alta)=CURDATE()) A 
GROUP BY ID_Vendedor WITH ROLLUP;
```